# Square of an odd integer is odd, square of even integer is even, what is the case for higher powers?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing

Are there rules for higher powers? It seems like even and odd is preserved by powers, but how do I prove that?

Comment: Properties of odd and even integers essentially states that an odd integer multiplied by an odd integer is odd, and an even integer multiplied by an even integer is even.

Answer (score 1):

You can show inductively that if we have $n\in\mathbb{N}$ odd, then $n^k$ is also odd $\forall k\in\mathbb{N}$. This follows from the fact that $k=3$ implies that
$$ n^3=n^2n.$$
We know that $n^2$ is odd and so is $n$, so the product of odds is odd, and so $n^3$ is odd for all odd $n$. You can repeat the process inductively.

You can repeat the argument symmetrically for all $n$ even.